# Do Docker secrets provide any additional security over a bind mount?

Tags: docker, devops, docker-secrets

From what I understand, Docker `secrets` and mounts (bind and volume) are all secure ways of managing secrets within a Docker container. I am wondering whether `secrets` has any security advantages?

I have an arbitrarily sized group of secrets. The secrets are kept in separate files in a folder. They periodically and automatically change. I want to make all of them available to a Docker container. Using a bind mount, I can mount their folder and they will all be accessible. Using `secrets`, I would have to specify each one in the Docker Compose file, increasing coupling and reducing maintainability. Is there any reason I should choose to go with `secrets` at the cost of maintainability?

Answer (score 5):

I was thinking the same recently, not wanting to actually use Docker Swarm or running anything distributed. In my case, the starting point was a project using `.env` containing secrets. If you have a simple Docker Compose project, there is no added value from using Docker secrets managed via `docker secret`. Note that without actually being a Swarm manager, you cannot even create secrets with `docker secret`!

Unbeknownst to many, Docker Compose actually [has support](https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/4368) for mounting secrets just like Docker Swarm, with the exception that it only works for local files. So [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/) would be a valid Docker Compose config:

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:latest
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/db_root_password
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/db_password
     secrets:
       - db_root_password
       - db_password

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/db_password
     secrets:
       - db_password

secrets:
   db_password:
     file: db_password.txt
   db_root_password:
     file: db_root_password.txt

volumes:
    db_data:
```

You don't really gain a lot of extra security or added value here, apart from the fact that you separate the volumes and other types of configuration (via env) from the secrets, which provides a little bit of extra safeguard against accidentally committing a secret to a repository, or mounting the wrong file to the wrong container, etc.

Answer (score -2):

if you are not using swarm, it is of no use to you.

> Docker secrets are only available to swarm services, not to standalone containers.

[using secrets](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/#about-secrets) has the following advantages

> Secrets are encrypted during transit and at rest in a Docker swarm.

you can leverage secrets in docker compose, which bring the [secrets](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#secrets-configuration-reference) features to containers regardless of swarm. docker compose just gives a nice interface\facede for mounting a secret file and exposing it to the container with a its naming conventions.

Comment: The first part about swarm is misleading. About the encryption, I don't see it as an advantage because it is the minimum required to be secure and volumes simply have no "transit and at rest" to secure? "docker compose just gives a nice interface\facede" if you come up with sources to back this, then I think that would be the answer (just syntactic sugar / a convenience wrapper => no other advantages)